# Coincidences amongst classifying spaces and Eilenberg Mac-Lane spaces

Tags: tag-removed, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, rt.representation-theory

Given that $$\mathbb{R}P^{\infty} = B O(1) = K(\widehat{O(1)}, 1)$$ $$\mathbb{C} P^{\infty} = B U(1) = K( \widehat{U(1)}, 2)$$ is there any way to make sense of $$\mathbb{H}P^{\infty} = B Sp(1)$$ in a similar manner using the representation theory of the non-abelian group $Sp(1) \cong Spin(3) \cong SU(2)$?

Comment: what does this hat notation mean?

Comment: Well, it looks like $K(\widehat{blah},n)$ is some sort of Eilenberg-MacLane space, but that is really the wrong way to think about it, as $blah$ isn't a discrete group.

Comment: ..the wrong way to think about it, if indeed that is what the notation is intended to convey. It may actually be representation theoretic.

Comment: In any case, disregarding the $K$-notation, the result is true and for the same reason the others are; $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$ is the quotient of $S^\infty$ by $Sp(1)$. The action is free and $S^\infty$ is contractible so (more or less) by definition the quotient is a $BSp(1)$.

Comment:  $\mathbb CP^{\infty}=K(\mathbb Z,2)$, no?

Comment: Will, yeah. Which is why I ask about notation.

Comment: In the first case, we have the group modulo the connected components of the identity, and $1$. I think there should always be a map from the classifying space to this type of Eilenberg Mac-Lane space. Not necessarily injective, maybe necessarily surjective.

In the second case, we have the fundamental group of the connected component. There should always be a map here, again, not necessarily injective.

But the third group is simply connected. So it has nothing to do with any discrete group. You're probably lost here.

Comment: $\widehat{G}$ denotes the dual group of a locally compact abelian group.  In particular, $\widehat{G} \cong G$ for finite groups (but not canonically), and you may recall $\widehat{U(1)} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ from Fourier series.  For a non-abelian group, the machinery of K(G,n)s cannot possibly work, which is the point of the question.

Answer (score 10):

There is a principal bundle
$$Sp(1)\to S^{4n+3} \to \mathbb{H}P^n$$
for each $n$, which on passing to the limit shows that $$\pi_i(\mathbb{H}P^\infty)\cong\pi_{i-1}(Sp(1))=\pi_{i-1}(S^3)$$
for each $i$. In particular, $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$ is not an Eilenberg-Mac Lane space.

However, this implies that it 'is' an Eilenberg-Mac Lane space after rationalization,
$$\mathbb{H}P^\infty\simeq_{\mathbb{Q}}K(\mathbb{Z},4).$$

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm certainly glad to see a 4.  I'm not familiar with rational homotopy theory, but I'd like to ask: is there some way of understanding the rationalization of BG in terms of the representation theory of G?  How can one explain this $\mathbb{Z}$ in the result for $BSp(1)$? 

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with representation theory, but perhaps there is some way to make sense of $\widehat{G}$ when $G$ is not abelian? A few ideas: one could replace continuous homomorphisms from $G$ to $S^1$ with ones to $S^3$, the unit quaternions? One could look at the group of continuous homomorphisms $Sp(1)$ to $S^1$ after rationalization? Maybe this is some appropriate notion of the dual group tensored with the rationals?

Comment: Also, you could try looking at Chapter 1 of "Algebraic models in Geometry" by Felix, Oprea and Tanré.

Comment: My first reaction was Tannaka-Krein dualtiy, but I feel like there should be something more concrete for SU(2), probably its Langlands dual group since it's reductive.  I'd be surprised if there wasn't any pre-existing work on/near this topic...

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Mark - that book looks really cool!

Comment: This is neat: in each of these three cases, you have $K( \pi_i(G), i+1 )$.

Comment: I just realized that this answer holds the clues to everything I've been thinking about, unfortunately I do not quite understand all of it. In particular:

Does your principal bundle / homotopy groups argument extend to any classifying space? I don't know enough homotopy theory to know what theorem you're calling on.

Comment: Hi Will, yes it does. For any group $G$ there is a principal bundle $G\to EG\to BG$, where $EG$ is a free, contractible $G$-space (this is the universal $G$-bundle). The long exact sequence of homotopy groups for this fibration has every third term zero, so $\pi_i(BG)\simeq \pi_{i-1}(G)$. This shows that $BG$ and $\Omega G$ (the based loop sapce of $G$) are weakly homotopy equivalent. If $G$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex (eg if it's compact Lie) then you can conclude they're homotopy equivalent.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just noticed a typo in my last comment: I should have said that $\Omega BG$ and $G$ are weakly homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Any group $G$ has a classifying space $BG$. It can be a finite group, an infinite discrete group a Lie group or any topological group.  The construction is always the same, find a contractible space, usually called $EG$, with a free continuous action by $G$. Then $BG$ is the quotient $EG/G$. One then has a fibration (in fact a principal bundle) $$G\to EG \to BG.$$ The long exact sequence in homotopy groups gives an isomorphism of $\pi_i G$ and $\pi_{i+1}BG$ (homotopy groups of $EG$ are all $0$).  When $G$ is discrete, this gives $\pi_1BG=G$ and $BG$ is aspherical (no higher homotopy groups). If $G$ is $S^1$, then, by definition, $BS^1=CP^{\infty}$. Moreover $\pi_1 S^1 = \pi_2 CP^{\infty}=\mathbb Z$  are the only nontrivial groups of $S^1$ and $CP^{\infty}$. So $CP^{\infty} = K(Z,2)$.  The $3$-sphere is a Lie group, a.k.a SU(2), but has lots of nontrivial homotopy groups.  So $BS^3$ is not $K(\mathbb Z,4)$ even though $\pi_4 BS^3 = \pi_3 S^3 = \mathbb Z$.

For $n\ge2$, $K(A,n)$ is defined only when $A$ is a abelian group.

Answer (score 5):

I claim that, in the equivalences you stated, duality has nothing to do with it. Specifically, if your viewpoint were correct, then for finite $G$, $BG(1)$ would be non-canonically isomorphic to $K(G,1)$. In fact, I claim that they are canonically isomorphic. Furthermore, the $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb CP^{\infty}$ is canonically isomporphic to the fundamental group, not the character group, of $U(1)$.

Argument: Since both these spaces represent functors, it suffices to consider the underlying functors. Eilenberg Mac-Lane spaces correspond to cohomology functors. It is easy to prove using Cech cohomology that cohomology with coefficients in $G$ naturally classifies principal $G$-bundles. This, of course, is exactly what the classifying space classifies - not dual to what the classifying space classifies.

$\mathbb CP^{\infty}$: There is an exact sequence $0\to\mathbb Z \to \mathbb C^+ \to \mathbb C^\times\to 0$, giving a map $H^1(X,\mathbb C^\times)\to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$. The image is discrete while the kernel, a quotient of $H^1(X,\mathbb C^{+})$, is connected, so the map is exactly the quotient by the connected component of the identity.

$H^1(X,\mathbb C^\times)$ classifies principal $\mathbb C^\times$ spaces. Continuously moving the bundle around in it corresponds to continuously deforming the bundle. These bundles up to derivation are exactly what $BU(1)$ classifies.

EDIT: Idea/sketch for a general proof of this equivalence: Let $G_n$ be the group of principal $G$-bundles on $S^{n}$. Then for some reason this should be equivalent to $\pi_{n-1}(G)$. Now, the values everywhere of good functors on the category of CW complexes (specifically, representable ones) depend only on the values they take on spheres. So suppose a group had only one nontrivial $G_n$. The principal $G$-spaces functor would then be equivalent to $H^n(X,G_n)$, giving an equivalence of classifying spaces.

Comment: Looking at Chern and Stiefel-Whitney classes, it seems like homology or cohomology should be involved more than homotopy groups. Unsure.

Comment: If we divide $S_n$ into two copies of $B_n$ glued together at $S_{n-1}$, and all fibrations on $B_{n}$ are trivial, then if we try to glue the fibrations together, the error will be an element of $\pi_{n-1}(G)$.

Comment: Why is $G_n$ a group? For nonabelian $G$ this is not true in general (modulo the fact you need to pass to isomorphism classes).

Comment: Um, good point. That would be another thing that's not explained. If it's isomorphic to $\pi_{n-1}$, then, that's why it's a group. Other than that, I don't know.

Alternatively, it might not matter too much. We can construct versions of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces for things other than groups. My argument sketch was motivated by this paper: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970209?seq=2

Answer (score 4):

This is not really an answer to the question posed but seems to be of relevance to people interested in the question (and is directly related to the case $BSU(2)\cong_{\mathbb{Q}}K(\mathbb{Z},4)$ mentioned by Mark Grant). There is a sequence of groups for which the classifying spaces are rationally products of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces: namely $BU(n)$. The $i$-th Chern class is an element of $H^{2i}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and hence can be thought of as homotopy class of map to a $K(\mathbb{Z},2i)$ space. Therefore you get a map

$$c_1\times\cdots\times c_n\colon BU(n)\to \prod_{i=1}^nK(\mathbb{Z},2i)$$

which turns out to be a rational homotopy equivalence. I learned this trick from Atiyah & Bott (http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/37156), Section 2. I guess the same should work for $SU(n)$ when you leave out the $c_1$ factor.